# How can i verify if a process is already running on powershell?

Tags: powershell, prompt

i have the following code

`Start-Process -windowstyle minimized  "C:/xampp/xampp-control.exe"`

There is a way to know if process is already running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to get the process ID of the process (use the `-PassThru` parameter of `Start-Process`) and then you can see if the process exists by ID. Example:

```
$processId = (Start-Process notepad -PassThru).Id
if ( Get-Process -Id $processId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) {
   "Process is running"
}
```