# Wait-Process not working in Windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have a .ps1 script for installing a piece of software with Wait-Process that was created with ISE on a W7 machine that when I try to run it on W10, it errors out.  Here is the script up until failure:

```
#Runs EnterpriseRx installer configured for PROD:
.\"EnterpriseRx.exe" /q /installType=0 /facilityID=999 /targetEnv=PROD 
/encryptFacility=0 /S /D=C:\McKesson\EnterpriseRx Production

#15 second notification letting user know install is running:
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("This process typically takes about 1 minute.  You will be 
notified when install is complete.",15,"EnterpriseRx - PROD is 
installing...",0x1)

#Wait for application to finish installing:
Wait-Process -name "EnterpriseRx.exe"
```

The error returned is this:

```
Wait-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "EnterpriseRx.exe". 
Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At C:\temp\EnterpriseRx Install TEST\EnterpriseRx Production - Desktop.ps1:9 
char:1
+ Wait-Process -name "EnterpriseRx.exe"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (EnterpriseRx.exe:String) [Wait-
Process], ProcessCommandException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WaitProcessCommand
```

I've tried changing the name to match what is showing in Task Manager, but with no success; I get the same error message.  Note: This process is a run-on-command.exe, I don't need to verify *if* it's running, I know it is running, I just need to know what it's running *as*.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i verify if a process is already running on powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642694/how-can-i-verify-if-a-process-is-already-running-on-powershell)

Comment: Why not use `Start-Process -FilePath "..." -ArgumentList "..." -Wait`?

Comment: @Sodawillow  

I don't play in Powershell all that often and this is something I cobbled together and it worked fine in W7 so I never thought about really streamlining it.  That being said...    

I set up the script with your suggestion and it works great for installing the app.  Now I just need to figure out why it's throwing an UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to create an icon in Public Desktop, but that is for another post if needed.    

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

While your installation is in progress, use another PowerShell window to run the following to find out what PowerShell sees for the process.

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.path -match "EnterpriseRx.exe"}
```

It most likely sees the process name as simply "EnterpriseRx" without the .exe on the end.

Comment: I tried that as that is how the W7 script was written and it failed on that name as well.

Comment: Is there any output from the command run second PowerShell window? It has to be run while EnterpriseRx.exe is still executing. Of course, the option using `Start-Process` will work around the issue by not needing to know the name of the process. It also has the added benefit of not accidentally selecting the wrong one if there is more than one process using the same name.

Answer (score 0):

An other attempt would be, starting the Process by `Start-Process`, as this Cmdlet will give you your Process-Object back. You can utilize this to wait:

```
#Runs EnterpriseRx installer configured for PROD:

$Process = Start-Process .\"EnterpriseRx.exe" -ArgumentList /q, /installType=0, /facilityID=999, /targetEnv=PROD, 
/encryptFacility=0, /S, /D=C:\McKesson\EnterpriseRx, Production -PassThru 

#15 second notification letting user know install is running:
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("This process typically takes about 1 minute.  You will be 
notified when install is complete.",15,"EnterpriseRx - PROD is 
installing...",0x1)

#Wait for application to finish installing:
$Process | Wait-Process
```

Comment: You'll need the `-PassThru` switch for `Start-Process` if you want to get your `Process` object back.